# How can I extend jquery-comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [jquery-comments](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments) to allow for commenting on my website. This works fine, but I would like to make some changes to how it works.

However, instead of making my changes to jquery-comments directly in the [jquery-comments.js](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments/blob/master/js/jquery-comments.js), I would like to put them in a different file, and extend/modify the `Comments` object if possible with my own functions.

For example I would like to change what happens in the function called `createCommentingFieldElement`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

When I initialize jquery-comments I can extend it with a function like this:

```
$('#comments-container').comments({
   getComments: function (success: any, error: any) {

      var extensionMethods = {
         doSomething: function () {
            // this is my extended function.
            // here you have the this object available.
         }
      }
   };

   $.extend(true, $('.jquery-comments').data('comments'), extensionMethods);
}
```

Your new jquery-comments extended function can now be called like this:

```
$('.jquery-comments').data('comments').doSomething();
```